# Squeeeeek-No-More-Floor-Repair-Kit stuck screw

Tags: removal

When inserting the joist finder screw, which is one of the components of the Squeeeeek-No-More-Floor-Repair-Kit, it got stuck midway so I can neither insert it nor remove it using a power drill. Does anyone have suggestions on how I can remove the Joist finder screw?

I was using the joist finder screw to find the joist on a carpeted floor. Recharging the power drill did not help.

[image: Squeek kit]

The joist finder screw is the long screw with threads only on the end.  It has a hex head that chucks directly into the drill.

Comment: I was using the joist finder screw to find the joist on a carpeted floor. Recharging the power drill did not help.

Comment: A picture would be helpful.

Comment: Does the joist finder screw just spin?  Or it will not spin at all?

Answer (score 2):

The joist finder screw is designed so that it will go through the subfloor and spin freely if there is no joist.  Once you find a spot where it does not spin freely, you have found a joist.  If there is no joist, you have to pull up on the drill to get the screw out.  I assume the screw isn't spinning freely.

If the screw is totally stuck and will not move, you have most likely ran into a nail embedded in the joist.  So, the good news is you found a joist.  To remove, grab the screw with a pair of vice lock pliers as close to the floor as possible.  If you just grab the head, it it likely to break as the shaft flexes and twists.  Tapping it with a hammer could help loosen it, but don't hit it hard enough to bend it.

Either the screw will break, or you will still not be able to turn it.  If all else fails, you will have to cut it off with a Dremel tool or other similar cut off tool.  If it comes to this, it will be hard to cut without leaving a mark on the carpet.  Protect the immediate area with masking tape (like a 1 square foot area).  The remaining shaft can be pounded flat with a hammer.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I was wondering if there are alternatives because I don't have a vise plier or hammer. For example can the screw be removed using a power drill?

Comment: If you chuck the screw into the drill, you can probably get more torque by grabbing the chuck with both hands and twisting than the drill motor provides if it is weak.  Vise locking pliers are an inexpensive and very common tool, so I’d really try to get a pair.

Answer (score 1):

Use channel lock pliers or vise grips to remove the screw.